# Using robotframework-imaplibrary python librarie in java based gradle projects

Tags: robotframework

Hi there is a python based library for testing email  [robotframework-imaplibrary](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework-imaplibrary#downloads), but our project is java based gradle. Therefore I am looking for a way how to include this imap library to my project. What I've tried so far is: downloaded the library, extracted it to the project temporary folder and then tried to include it to the robot script by using

```
Library   ../libraries/robotframework-imaplibrary/src/ImapLibrary
```

but it didn't work. I am new to Robot, can someone help me how to do it properly?

[image]

Comment: How exactly did you try to include the library?

Comment: As I mentioned I tried to do like this: Library ../libraries/robotframework-imaplibrary/src/ImapLibrary - this didn't work, then I tried with this Library ../libraries/robotframework-imaplibrary/src/ImapLibrary/__init__.py  - this also didn't work.  Mayne I should specify something in gradle?

Comment: As I see, the library is not in `src` folder but in `test/utest`. And did I understand you correctly - you want to impoer a Python library into a Java project?

Comment: Yes i tried this as well, and got an error:  Importing test library '/Users/d072160/work/email/email-service/src/test/robot/libraries/robotframework-imaplibrary/test/utest/test_imaplibrary.py' failed: ImportError: No module named ImapLibrary

Comment: Do you want to import a Python library into a Java project?

Comment: And yes, this is correct, I am trying to import a Python library into a Java project, since according to robot documentation It's possible to use both Python and Java based libraries at one place, but the problem is how to specify Python based library in a correct way in Java gradle project...

Comment: It seems that you misunderstood something. Which IDE is your screen shot from?

Comment: I am using intelliJ.  The thing is before I joined my team they used this imap library with java project and and it was working fine...but previous QA left and nobody know how it was done...as usual...and there is no example left which I can use